# How to properly get the name, surname and answers to custom questions, for each participant, so is possible to introduce all info in DB?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a context where a conference can have 1 or more registration types and the user can do a registration at a conference in 1 or more registration types of the conference.

So for example, the conference with id 1 has two registration types associated, the registration type "general" with id 1 and "plus" with id 2. The registration type "general" has 6 custom questions associated with it, the registration type "plus" don't have any custom question associated with it.

When a user is doing a registration in a conference and select quantity "2" for the registration type "plus" and click "Next" the user goes to the registration page. In this page, there is the registration form and the user only needs to enter his name and surname and click "Register". The `$request->all` shows like below, the participant's array stores the name, surname, and registration type of each participant:

```
array:4 [▼
  "participant" => array:2 [▼
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "John"
      "surname" => "W"
      "rtypes" => "2"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "Jake"
      "surname" => "K"
      "rtypes" => "2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

And it works fine all info is correctly stored using the `storeRegistrationInfo()` method below.

**Doubt:**

But if the user is doing a registration and select quantity "2" for the registration type "general" and click "Next", the registration type "general" has 6 custom questions associated with it. So in the registration form the user needs to enter his name and surname but the user also needs to answer the 6 required custom questions.  My doubt is how to store for each participant the answers to the custom questions, do you know how to properly achieve that? Because as it is, after the user enter the name, surname and the answer to the 6 custom questions and click "Next", the `$request->all()` dont shows the correct info, it shows like:

```
array:4 [▼
  "participant" => array:4 [▼
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "John"
      "surname" => "W"
      "answer" => "test.jpg"
      "question_id" => "6"
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    " 1" => array:1 [▼
      "answer" => "option 1"
    ]
    2 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "Jake"
      "surname" => "K"
      "answer" => "test.jpg"
      "question_id" => "6"
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    " 2" => array:1 [▼
      "answer" => "option 2"
    ]
  ]
  "participant_question_required" => array:12 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
    3 => "1"
    4 => "1"
    5 => "1"
    6 => "1"
    7 => "1"
    8 => "1"
    9 => "1"
    10 => "1"
    11 => "1"
  ]
]
```

And so instead of the `storeRegistration()` stores all necessary info it appear always 3 validation errors:

```
The field name is mandatory.
The field surname is mandatory.
Please answer the custom questions.
```

Do you know why? The user anwers all this fields but it appear that validation errors.

Below there is the `RegistrationController` `storeRegistration()` method that stores the registration info:

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{

    public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
    {
        $rules = [
            'participant.*.name' => 'required',
            'participant.*.surname' => 'required',
        ];

        $customMessages = [
            'participant.*.name.required' => 'The field name is required.',
            'participant.*.surname.required' => 'The field surname is required.'
        ];

        if (isset($request->participant_question_required)) {

            foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $key => $value) {
                $rule = 'string|max:255';

                // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
                if ($value) {
                    $rule = 'required|' . $rule;
                }

                // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
                $rules["participant_question.{$key}"] = $rule;

                $customMessages += [
                    'participant_question.*.required' => 'Please answer to the required custom questions.',
                ];
            }
        }

        $this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);

        $user = Auth::user(); 

        // insert registration in DB
        $registration = Registration::create([
            'conference_id' => $id,
            'user_that_did_the_registration' => $user->id,
            'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C'
        ]);

        // list of all participants (a registration can have multiple participants)
        $participants_list = $request->get('participant');

        // add all participants to DB
        foreach ($participants_list as $participant) {

            $name = $participant['name'];
            $surname = $participant['surname'];
            $participant_result = Participant::create([
                'name' => $name,
                'surname' => $surname,
                'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                'registration_type_id' => $participant['rtypes']
            ]);

             // store all answers to the custom questions in DB 
            if (isset($participant['question_id'])) {
                $answer = Answer::create([
                    'question_id' => $participant['question_id'],
                    'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
                    'answer' => $participant['answer'],
                ]);
            }
        }

        Session::flash('registration_success', 'You are registered in the conference');
        return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]) . '#myTickets');
    }
}
```

Registration Form:

```
<form method="post"
      action="https://proj.test/conference/1/conference-test/registration/storeRegistration">


        <h6>Participant - 1 - general</h6>

        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="namegeneral_1"
                   class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input type="text" required id="namegeneral_1"
                   name="participant[name]"
                   class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="surnamegeneral_1"
                   class="text-gray">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" required id="surnamegeneral_1"
                   class="form-control"
                   name="participant[surname]" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Input text custom question</label>

            <input type='text' name='participant[1][answer]' class='form-control' required>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="1"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Long text custom question</label>
            <textarea name='participant[1][answer]' class='form-control' rows='3' required></textarea>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="2"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Checkbox custom question</label>
            <div class='checkbox-group  required'>
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant[1][answer]' value='check1' class='form-check-input'>
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check1</label>
                </div>
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant[1][answer]' value='check2' class='form-check-input'>
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="3"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Radio button custom question</label>
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant[1][answer]' value='radio button 1' class='form-check-input'
                       required> <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">radio button 1</label></div>
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant[1][answer]' value='radio button 2' class='form-check-input'
                       required> <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">radio button 2</label></div>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="4"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Select menu custom question</label>
            <select name='participant[ 1][answer]' class='form-control' required>
                <option value='option 1'>option 1</option>
                <option value='option 2'>option 2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="5"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">File custom question</label>
            <input type='file' name='participant[1][answer]' class='form-control' required>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="6"
                   name="participant[1][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="participant[1][rtypes]"
               value="1"/>


        <h6>Participant - 2 - general</h6>


        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="namegeneral_2"
                   class="text-gray">Name</label>
            <input type="text" required id="namegeneral_2"
                   name="participant[name]"
                   class="form-control" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
            <label for="surnamegeneral_2"
                   class="text-gray">Surname</label>
            <input type="text" required id="surnamegeneral_2"
                   class="form-control"
                   name="participant[surname]" value="">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Input type text custom question</label>
            <input type='text' name='participant[2][answer]' class='form-control' required>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="1"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Long text custom question</label>
            <textarea name='participant[2][answer]' class='form-control' rows='3' required></textarea>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="2"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Checkbox custom question</label>
            <div class='checkbox-group  required'>
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant[2][answer]' value='check1' class='form-check-input'>
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check1</label>
                </div>
                <div class='form-check'>
                    <input type='checkbox' name='participant[2][answer]' value='check2' class='form-check-input'>
                    <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>check2</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="3"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Radio button custom question</label>

            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant[2][answer]' value='radio button 1' class='form-check-input'
                       required> <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">radio button 1</label></div>
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant[2][answer]' value='radio button 2' class='form-check-input'
                       required> <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">radio button 2</label></div>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="4"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">Select menu custom question</label>
            <select name='participant[ 2][answer]' class='form-control' required>
                <option value='option 1'>option 1</option>
                <option value='option 2'>option 2</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="5"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="participant_question">File custom question</label>

            <input type='file' name='participant[2][answer]' class='form-control' required>
            <input type="hidden"
                   name="participant_question_required[]"
                   value="1">
            <input type="hidden"
                   value="6"
                   name="participant[2][question_id]"/>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="participant[2][rtypes]"
               value="1"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Register"/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you add the form?

Comment: I updated with the generated HTML form, in this case the user selected quantity "2" for the registration type "general" so in the form there is fields for 2 participants.

Comment: please add `dd($rules);` result.

Comment: I updated with that.

Comment: @john do you get any solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
Change name="participant[{{$counter}}][surname]" to name="participant[surname]" 
and
Change name="participant[{{$counter}}][name]" to name="participant[name]"
```

and validations will work.

**Understand what you are sending**

If you recheck your `$request` then you will see that `$participent is multidimentional array` and only first array is having name index but  second array does not contain `name` so it is throwing error back.

validation `participent.*.name` want only one dimensional array of names like this:

```
$participent[0] = 'name1'
$participent[1] = 'name2'
$participent[2] = 'name3'
$participent[3] = 'name4'
```

that means every index of `$participent` array must have `name` index, but you are sending it wrong as below.

```
$participent[0] = [name=> somename, ...]
$participent[1] = [question=>'abc', answer => 'abc']
```

So second index of `$participent array` does not have `name` index and your validations wants it.

Comment: Thanks, but same issue with participant[surname] and participant[name] instead of participant[{{$counter}}][surname] and participant[{{$counter}}][name].

Comment: Its like "array:10 [▼
  "participant" => array:4 [▼
    "name" => "Jake"
    "surname" => "W"
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "answer" => "img.jpg"
      "question_id" => "6"
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    " 1" => array:1 [▼
      "answer" => "option 1"
    ]
  ]
  "participant_question_required" => array:6 [▼
    0 => "1"
    1 => "1"
    2 => "1"
    3 => "1"
    4 => "1"
    5 => "1"
  ]".

Comment: you are sending your request still in wrong way: participant has 4 indices and only first have name field you should change your request structure so that participant array should contain name index

Comment: your last hidden field name is participant array that is the actual reason of the error. Change its name and validate it separately

Comment: Thanks, so it should be necessary the $counter so its possible to store in each index of the array the details  (name, surname, answer,..) of a specific participant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177880/discussion-between-afraz-ahmad-and-john).

Answer (score 1):

Update your registration form using the following form fields :

- change `participant[name]` to `participant_name[user_index]`. [eg. `participan_name[1]`], where `user_index` is the index of quantity.
- change `participant[surname]` to `participant_surname[user_index]`. [eg. `participan_surname[1]`], where `user_index` is the index of quantity.
- change `participant[1][answer]` to `answer[user_index][question_id]`. [eg. `participan_surname[1][5]`], where `user_index` is the index of quantity and `question_id` is the primary_key of the question.
- change `participant_question_required[]` to `participant_question_required[question_id]`. [eg. `participant_question_required[5]`], where `question_id` is the primary_key of the question. set it's value to `1` if required else set to `0`.
- You may ignore `participant[1][question_id]`.[In this method this field is not required]

Update controller- validator using the following method:

```
$rules = [
    'participant_name.*'     => 'required',
    'participant_surname.*'  => 'required',
];

$customMessages = [
    'participant_name.*.required'    => 'The field name is required.',
    'participant_surname.*.required' => 'The field surname is required.'
];

//second section
if (isset($request->participant_question_required)) {

    foreach ($request->participant_question_required as $questionId => $value) {
        $answerRule = 'string|max:255';

        // if this was required, ie 1, prepend "required|" to the rule
        if ($value == 1) {
            // add the individual rule for this array key to the $rules array
            $rules['answer.*.$questionId'] = 'required|' . $answerRule;

            $customMessages += [
                'answer.*.$questionId'' => [
                    'unique' => 'Please answer to the required custom questions.',
                ],
            ];
        }
    }
}

$this->validate($request, $rules, $customMessages);
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thanks, but also dont work like that. The issue is only when the user select registration types that have custom questions associated. I updated the question to explain better.

Comment: Do you know what can be the issue? The issue should be in the approach in storing the custom answers in the array.

Comment: @John Do you really need the data as the array of `participant[][]`?

Comment: Its not necessary, if it works with other approach its ok.

Comment: Am testing some methods on my side. I will update here if there any progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178034/discussion-between-ab-and-john).